# Problems with android UI design

Tags: android

I wanna apply this style into my project which contain drawer layout. I have seen this [website](http://android-holo-colors.com/) provide a very useful generator and my problem is I cant apply it into my project. Did anyone ever experience of it? Plz share your thoughts guys :)

Comment: Just click on the download.zip button

Comment: I did, but I can use them to customize my UI project.

Comment: I mean I cant (sorry)

Comment: You just only copy-paste in your project or you called it in your AndroidManifest.xml too ?

Comment: ho ho .. i think you are facing problem in adding xml style file to your controls right ?

Comment: I copied the xml and picture and place in drawable then called them in style then call in AndroidManifest

Comment: You must assign that style to `android:theme` of `<application >` tag

Comment: Can u guys try for once and show the step and code?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Comment: I did it already Glenn, but nth change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading, be sure to extract the files, and place them into the layouts directory of your android project.

Then, make sure the name you have for them is lined up with the view you've set for your activity.

So if you wanted to generate the main screen, the process would be:

1. Make it on the website
2. Download the .zip
3. Extract the contents
4. Move the .xml files to the layout directory of your project
5. In the activity, set the content view to the name of the .xml file

If you can't get it to work that way, try making a new layout in your IDE, then go to the text/code view, and directly copy+paste the content of the .xml file.

Comment: Even when you copy the code to a new layout? Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution ......

1.I hope you will download the ZIP file into that website.

2.then you will unzip that file and you can get the folder.

3.that folder will contain the res folder.

4.you will replace the res folder into your corresponding new project res.

5.then you will get the error in the themes_your_given_name.//while you creating the zip.

6.Because in that file starts with _ so you just change into your new name and it will make some error.

7.Go to values->themes_name and there you will change your current name and the parent theme.

8.And then you go to your mainfest file and change the theme of your application into you new Custom theme..like this

```
 <application
    android:label="Trail"
    android:theme="@style/CustomOwn">   //custom theme..    

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.trail.MainActivity"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```